# Getting an all None gradient in my custom loss and gradient code in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, customization, loss-function

I am trying to write a pretty darn basic loss function in tensorflow 2.0. In summary, I have 5 classes and I want to train without grouping any of them, using one hot encoding. I want my model to predict each input with a value for each of the 5 classes. Afterwards, I would like to try and get the two highest values, and if they are either 3 or 4, I would like to classify it as "good" and if it's not then "bad." Lastly, I want my loss to be 1-precision where the precision as I said has true positives in the following situations:
1. Model guessed 3 and real class was 3
2. Model guessed 3 and real class was 4
3. Model guessed 4 and real class was 3
4. Model guessed 4 and real class was 4

Again, I know I could just change the labels of my data but I would rather not do that.
I used some nice already written metric to write my loss, here it is:

```py
#@tf.function
def my_loss(output,real,threeandfour=1,weights=loss_weights,mod=m):
  m = tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(thresholds=0.5)
  m.update_state(real,output,sample_weight=weights)
  shape_0=tf.shape(output)[0]
  #shape_1=tf.constant(2,dtype=tf.int32)
  shape_1=2
  halfs=tf.math.multiply(tf.constant(0.5,dtype=tf.float32),tf.ones((shape_0,shape_1),dtype=tf.float32))
  thrsfrs_1=output[:,2:4]
  thrsfrs=tf.cast(thrsfrs_1,dtype=tf.float32)
  logs_1=tf.math.greater(thrsfrs,halfs)
  logs=tf.cast(logs_1,dtype=tf.float32)
  print('shape of log: ',np.shape(logs))
  print('few logs: ',logs,)

  num_of_3_4s_in_model=tf.reduce_sum(logs)
  prec_1=tf.math.divide(m.result(),num_of_3_4s_in_model)
  prec=tf.cast(prec_1,dtype=tf.float32)
  return tf.math.subtract(tf.constant(1,dtype=tf.float32),prec)
```

The gradient function:

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      tape.watch(model.trainable_variables)
      y_=model(X_train)
      print('y_: ',y_)
      loss_value=my_loss(y_,tf_one_hot_train,mod=m,weights=loss_weights)
      #loss_value=tf.cast(loss_value,dtype=tf.float32)
      print('loss_value: ',loss_value)
grads=tape.gradient(loss_value,model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

It does succeed in getting a loss value which is tensorflow and seems alright. This is the gradient and error I'm getting:

```
python
got grads
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-370-2f8f4b783a7b> in <module>()
     23 
     24 #optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables), global_step)
---> 25 optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
     26 
     27 #print("Step: {},         Loss: {}".format(global_step.numpy(),

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    973   if not filtered:
    974     raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %
--> 975                      ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))
    976   if vars_with_empty_grads:
    977     logging.warning(

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense_40/kernel:0', 'dense_40/bias:0', 'dense_41/kernel:0', 'dense_41/bias:0', 'dense_42/kernel:0', 'dense_42/bias:0', 'dense_43/kernel:0', 'dense_43/bias:0', 'dense_44/kernel:0', 'dense_44/bias:0', 'dense_45/kernel:0', 'dense_45/bias:0', 'dense_46/kernel:0', 'dense_46/bias:0', 'dense_47/kernel:0', 'dense_47/bias:0']
```

I've tried to include the @tf.function, I tried to turn the 2 into an int, etc. I also tried to do it with many different other functions like the tf.confusion_matrix or even without anything, including just tf.arg_max and stuff like that. Nothing seemed to work.

I'm adding the most tensorflow-y code for my loss that I could think of. The same thing keeps happening. I use it with tensorflow objects, numpy objects, I checked that my inputs are from zero to one, still None gradients. Here is my tensorflowy loss:

```py
#@tf.function
def my_loss(real,output):
  threeandfour=tf.constant(1,dtype=tf.float32)
  #turning real into real classes (opposite of one hot encoding)
  real_classes=tf.argmax(real,axis=1)
  real_classes=tf.cast(real_classes,dtype=tf.float32)
  #tf.print('real_classes: ',real_classes)

  pred_classes=tf.argmax(output,axis=1)
  pred_classes=tf.cast(pred_classes,dtype=tf.float32)
  #tf.print('pred_classes: ',pred_classes)

  #checking how many 3s and 4s there are in both
  good_real=(tf.logical_or(tf.equal(real_classes,3),tf.equal(real_classes,4)))
  good_real=tf.cast(good_real,dtype=tf.float32)
  #tf.print('good_real: ',good_real)

  good_pred=(tf.logical_or(tf.equal(pred_classes,3),tf.equal(pred_classes,4)))
  good_pred=tf.cast(good_pred,dtype=tf.float32)
  #tf.print('good_pred: ',good_pred)

  #which ones do the real and model agree on
  same=tf.math.equal(good_pred,good_real)
  same=tf.cast(same,dtype=tf.float32)
  #print('same: ',same)

  #which ones do they both think are good (3 and 4)
  same_goods=tf.math.multiply(same,good_pred)
  same_goods=tf.cast(same_goods,dtype=tf.float32)
  #print('same goods: ',same_goods)

  #number of ones they both think are good
  num_same_goods=tf.reduce_sum(same_goods)
  num_same_goods=tf.cast(num_same_goods,dtype=tf.float32)
  #print('num_same_goods: ',num_same_goods)

  #number of ones model thinks are good
  num_pred_goods=tf.reduce_sum(good_pred)
  num_pred_goods=tf.cast(num_pred_goods,dtype=tf.float32)
  #print('num_pred_goods: ',num_pred_goods)

  #making sure not to divide by 0
  non_zero_num=tf.math.add(num_pred_goods,tf.constant(0.0001,dtype=tf.float32))
  #precision
  prec=tf.math.divide(num_same_goods,non_zero_num)
  prec=tf.cast(prec,dtype=tf.float32)
  #tf.print('prec: ',prec)
  #1-precision
  one_minus_prec=tf.math.subtract(tf.constant(1,dtype=tf.float32),prec)
  one_minus_prec=tf.cast(one_minus_prec,dtype=tf.float32)

  return one_minus_prec
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with `tensorflow==2.0.0a0`.

Updating to `2.0.0b1` resolved my case

```
pip install -U tensorflow==2.0.0b1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @alexey. Unfortunately I was already using tensorflow 2.0.0 beta-1 and when I reinstalled it the way you wrote it, it still give me all None gradients.

Comment: I looked again and noticed another potential source of the problem. try out putting `grads = tape.gradient(loss_value,model.trainable_variables)` inside `with` block

Comment: According to TF docs `grads = tape.gradient(loss_value,model.trainable_variables)` goes outside de with block. I am trying to figure out what is happening

Comment: Thank you for trying to help!!

Comment: facing the same problem what is the solution??