# GradientTape: getting gradient of nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to calculate the gradient within tensorflow, however returning `None`. I have already adjusted the type to be `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor`, however htis did not solve the problem.

This is the code so far:

```
accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')
loss = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy('loss')
  
for epoch in range(epochs):
    accuracy.reset_states()
    loss.reset_states()
    
    for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_train, y_train, batch_size):
        imgs = batch[0]
        labels = batch[1]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            preds = model(imgs)
            
            labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.float32)
            
            #print(loss(labels,preds))
            # Loss is crossentropy loss with regularization term for each parameter
            total_loss = loss(labels, preds) #+l2_penalty(model, theta_A) 

        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
        model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
       
        accuracy.update_state(labels, preds)
        loss.update_state(labels, preds)
        print("\rEpoch: {}, Batch: {}, Loss: {:.3f}, Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(
            epoch+1, batch+1, loss.result().numpy(), accuracy.result().numpy()), flush=True, end='')
        print("")
   
print("Task B accuracy after training trained model on Task B: {}".format(model.evaluate(task_B_test)))
print("Task A accuracy after training trained model on Task B: {}".format(model.evaluate(task_A_test)))
```

does anybody know why it's turning none or how i can fix this?

Edit: My error message looks the following:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> C:\Users\DC5DE~1.ALB\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13300/818221091.py in 
> 34         grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
> 35
> ---> 36         model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
> 37
> 38         accuracy.update_state(labels, preds)

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'apply_gradients'

Since I am not sure if it has to do with how I pass my image data to GradientTape here is my function for the minibatch:

```
def iterate_minibatches(inputs, targets, batchsize, shuffle=False):
    assert inputs.shape[0] == targets.shape[0]
    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(inputs.shape[0])
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, inputs.shape[0] - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batchsize]
        else:
            excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
        yield inputs[excerpt], targets[excerpt]
```

Also: a similar problem was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383467/getting-an-all-none-gradient-in-my-custom-loss-and-gradient-code-in-tensorflow-2), however without any solution that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a few things mixed up. You either need to call `model.compile` or define your own optimizer and use it. Also, you should not mix up your metrics with your loss function. Here is a working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')
metric = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy('metric_ categorical_crossentropy')
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
epochs = 2
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, input_shape=(1,))
]) 
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((50, 1)), tf.random.normal((50, 3)))).batch(5)
for epoch in range(epochs):
    accuracy.reset_states()
    metric.reset_states()
    
    for i, batch in enumerate(dataset):
        imgs = batch[0]
        labels = batch[1]
        print(imgs.shape, labels.shape)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            preds = model(imgs)
                      
            #print(loss(labels,preds))
            # Loss is crossentropy loss with regularization term for each parameter
            total_loss = loss(labels, preds) #+l2_penalty(model, theta_A) 

        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
       
        accuracy.update_state(labels, preds)
        metric.update_state(labels, preds)
        print("\rEpoch: {}, Batch: {}, Loss: {:.3f}, Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(
            epoch+1, i+1, metric.result().numpy(), accuracy.result().numpy()), flush=True, end='')
        print("")
```

```
Epoch: 1, Batch: 1, Loss: 4.209, Accuracy: 0.200
Epoch: 1, Batch: 2, Loss: 1.641, Accuracy: 0.400
Epoch: 1, Batch: 3, Loss: 1.294, Accuracy: 0.333
Epoch: 1, Batch: 4, Loss: 1.025, Accuracy: 0.300
Epoch: 1, Batch: 5, Loss: -0.110, Accuracy: 0.320
Epoch: 1, Batch: 6, Loss: 0.316, Accuracy: 0.267
Epoch: 1, Batch: 7, Loss: -0.118, Accuracy: 0.257
Epoch: 1, Batch: 8, Loss: -0.284, Accuracy: 0.225
Epoch: 1, Batch: 9, Loss: -0.249, Accuracy: 0.244
Epoch: 1, Batch: 10, Loss: -0.464, Accuracy: 0.260
Epoch: 2, Batch: 1, Loss: 4.468, Accuracy: 0.200
Epoch: 2, Batch: 2, Loss: 1.578, Accuracy: 0.400
Epoch: 2, Batch: 3, Loss: 1.012, Accuracy: 0.400
Epoch: 2, Batch: 4, Loss: 0.836, Accuracy: 0.350
Epoch: 2, Batch: 5, Loss: -0.294, Accuracy: 0.360
Epoch: 2, Batch: 6, Loss: 0.168, Accuracy: 0.300
Epoch: 2, Batch: 7, Loss: -0.201, Accuracy: 0.286
Epoch: 2, Batch: 8, Loss: -0.634, Accuracy: 0.250
Epoch: 2, Batch: 9, Loss: -0.552, Accuracy: 0.267
Epoch: 2, Batch: 10, Loss: -0.920, Accuracy: 0.280
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy` for loss computation instead of `tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy` which works differently and will stop gradient propagation.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately the error remains...

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'apply_gradients' The error message is because you didn't compile your model with an optimizer using `model.compile(...)`